# Does NASM include the segment registers in the generated machine instructions in 32-bit x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

I have read that a 32-bit x86 CPU uses segment registers when accessing memory, but when I write Assembly code in NASM, I don't have to specify any segment registers.

So does that mean that NASM include the segment registers in the generated machine instructions, or am I missing something?

Comment: The segment register used is implicit, most instructions use `ds`. When `ebp/esp` are used in the address then `ss` is used implicitly. Some specific purpose instruction use a fixed segment (e.g. `stosb`). The segment used in loads and stores can be overridden explicitly (e.g. `mov [cs:label], eax` in NASM) if the programmer need so. In 32-bit assembly, using a mainstream OS, this is seldom necessary (only exceptions being the TLS and the PEB/TEB in Windows).

Comment: To make things clear, "used" refers to the cpu, not nasm.

Answer (score 4):

Unless explicitly overridden by segment override prefixes, the segment registers used are derived from the addressing mode:

- `cs` is used for code fetches
- `ss` is used for memory accesses using `esp` or `ebp` as the base register (with any addressing mode)
- `es` is used as the segment for `edi` when using string instructions
- `ds` is used in any other situation.

Refer to the Intel manuals for details.